# why can't I ping the external IP address of my Google Compute Engine instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I created a Google Compute Engine instance but can not ping its external IP address (173.255.118.164).

I can ssh into the instance via gcutil, but I can not ping the external address from my home computer.

With Amazon EC2, this is straightforward and just works.

What's up with Google ?

Answer (score 23):

By default, all incoming traffic is blocked except for SSH. To enable ICMP (ping), you can create a firewall rule by running:

```
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-ping --direction=INGRESS --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=icmp --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0
```

This will allow you to ping all of your instances on the default network. Firewall rules can also be created in the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) --> Compute Engine --> Networks UI.

You can also create rules which only apply to groups of instances, etc. Details in the [documentation for Networks and Firewalls](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#addingafirewall).

The same steps apply for allowing other kinds of traffic. If you want to allow HTTP traffic, for example:

```
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-http --direction=INGRESS --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:80 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Thanks for the patient response, which I could have figured out if I had actually read the documentation. :-)

Comment: It sounds like this answered your question. If so, please mark the question answered by clicking the check mark next to this answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I keep having following error: `-bash: gcutil: command not found`

Comment: I guess OP meant `gsutil`, not `gcutil`.
Having said that, I'm not aware of a way to use `gsutil` for SSH - for that you'd need `gcloud compute ssh`. Bummer.