# Unable to reach e7502.ce.akamaiedge.net from google compute engine instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have been able to reach e7502.ce.akamaiedge.net from compute engine instances until yesterday.

Tried to ping the host, giving me the following result:

```
$ ping -w 5 e7502.ce.akamaiedge.net
```

PING e7502.ce.akamaiedge.net (23.35.168.70) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- e7502.ce.akamaiedge.net ping statistics ---

5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5000ms

While the host is reachable from another PC:

```
>ping 23.35.168.70
```

Pinging 23.35.168.70 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 23.35.168.70: bytes=32 time=186ms TTL=54

Reply from 23.35.168.70: bytes=32 time=187ms TTL=54

Reply from 23.35.168.70: bytes=32 time=186ms TTL=54

Reply from 23.35.168.70: bytes=32 time=187ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 23.35.168.70:

Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

Minimum = 186ms, Maximum = 187ms, Average = 186ms

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd consider reading through the following thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903859/why-cant-i-ping-the-external-ip-address-of-my-google-compute-engine-instance

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, the IP that I wanted to reach is an IP of an external site. I used to be able to ping it.