# GCE : Unable to ping its own external-ip address

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am unable to ping external-ips of my Google-Compute-Engines, from within the GCE machine. 
But when trying from outside network (from my laptop), its able to ping.

**From within GCE vm :**

```
rharoon002@es-01-client-01:/$ wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -
130.211.147.88
rharoon002@es-01-client-01:/$ ping 130.211.147.88
PING 130.211.147.88 (130.211.147.88) 56(84) bytes of data.
....... (hangs for ever)
```

**From local system (laptop):**

```
rharoon002@RHAROON00235 C:\Users\rharoon002
> ping 130.211.147.88

Pinging 130.211.147.88 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 130.211.147.88: bytes=32 time=238ms TTL=43
Reply from 130.211.147.88: bytes=32 time=236ms TTL=43
Reply from 130.211.147.88: bytes=32 time=237ms TTL=43
Reply from 130.211.147.88: bytes=32 time=238ms TTL=43

Ping statistics for 130.211.147.88:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 236ms, Maximum = 238ms, Average = 237ms
```

Comment: It's weird, mine works fine. Could you show your firewall settings?

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because of firewall settings. You may need to add a firewall rule. I found this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17904142/4743540.